# Ruby - Run external file in new window

Tags: ruby, windows, file, external, require

I have a ruby script (script1.rb):

```
puts "Hello world!"
puts "I am a script"
```

I have another script (scrip2.rb):

```
puts "I will run a separate script"
require 'script1.rb'
puts "I have finished."
```

I want to be able to run `script1.rb` in a new window and have `script2.rb` still run while `script1.rb` is running.

So: Script2 puts "I will run a separate script"
Then, it runs script1 and puts "I have finished." at the same time while script1 is `puts`ing its text.

I hope this makes sense and that there's a solution.

Operating system is Windows.

Thanks, Reece

Comment: What Windowing System are you using? Ruby doesn't have a concept of "Window", so you will need to use some external library, which usually is specific to the Windowing System or Desktop Environment. Motif works very different from Haiku, for example.

Comment: use `Process.fork`

Comment: kiddorails said to use `Process.fork`. Just asking how I could apply that to this?

Comment: Is this on Windows?

Comment: Yep. Trying to run another script in a new window with Process.fork

Comment: There is no fork on Windows...

Comment: Is there any other way I could do what I'm trying to do? Is there a `fork` alternative?

Comment: Its complexity depends on what information needs shared between the two "windows". If they can run independently, it is quite simple to just spawn another process or thread and run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Ruby is really just a scripting language without any GUI components or concepts of screens or windows.

However on Windows, and without using any GUI gem, you CAN create a new `cmd.exe` command prompt with a new script using a trick like this:

```
puts "I will run a separate script"
system('start cmd.exe /K ruby "some ruby script.rb"')
puts "I have finished."
```

This will run the Ruby script `some ruby script.rb` as a new process in a new command prompt window. Perhaps that gets you what you need.

Comment: Thanks! You've really helped. If it's not any hassle, is there any way you can use this with files that have spaces in their names? Example: `script one.rb`

Comment: Use: `system('start cmd.exe /K ruby "script with spaces.rb"')`. Notice how I enclose the whole string in single quotes, and use double quotes for the file name.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.